# If the function $f(x)=ax+b$ has its own inverse,then the ordered pair $(a,b)$ can be

Tags: functions, inverse

If the function $f(x)=ax+b$ has its own inverse,then the ordered pair $(a,b)$ can be
$(A)(1,0)\hspace{1cm}(B)(-1,0)\hspace{1cm}(C)(-1,1)\hspace{1cm}(D)(1,1)$
This is a more than one options correct type question.The answer given is $(A),(B),(C)$.
I do not know what it means by "the function $f(x)=ax+b$ has its own inverse."
Does it mean that $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)?$
I am stuck here and can not proceed further.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: I think the text has a typo. I belive it should read "is its own inverse" instead of "have its own inverse". Which does indeed mean what you think it means. and is consistent with the answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to the given answer, I think what you thought is right. Do the equation $$ax+b=\frac{x}{a}-\frac{b}{a}$$ and find the proper values of $a$ and $b$. If for all values of $x$ we have the above equation so $a=1/a,~~a\neq0$ and $b=\frac{-b}{a}$ . The results is $a=\pm1$ and if $a=+1$ then $b=0$ and if $a=-1$ then $b$ would be any numbers for exaple $1$.